# How to increment of 1 after 5th zero?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to increament of 1 after 5th zero but when I click the up button it shows me just 1 rather 000001.

```
<div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="000001">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>                          
(function ($) {
   $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
      $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1);
   });
   $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
      $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1);
   });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
  var noOfZer = 6; // Total length of number, for you number is 6
  var num=parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1;
  console.log(String('000000' + num).slice(-1 * noOfZer));
```

<kbd>**[`demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/ubfdzms1/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try

```
 $('.spinner input').val( "00000"+(parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1));
```

and

```
 $('.spinner input').val( "00000"+(parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1));
```

because `parseInt()` returns just  the integer value, which is excluding zeros

Answer (score 1):

You may look at below code. Actually the issue was with `parseInt`. If you execute over the string like `000002` it will give you a result of `2`. So after doing mathematical calculation we again need to formulate the required string by prepending the zeros as per length:

```js
(function($) {
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val(prependZero(parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1, 6));
  });
  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val(prependZero(parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1, 6));
  });

  function prependZero(num, size) {
    if (num <= 0)
      num = 0;
    var s = num + "";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group spinner">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="000001">
  <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method as follows:

Here n is the number

```
var output = [], n, padded;
for (n=0; n<=9999; n++) {
    padded = ('0000'+n).slice(-4); // Prefix three zeros, and get the last 4 chars
    output.push(padded);
}
console.log(output); // ["0000", "0001", ..., "9999"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qJSBg/